# Visual Studio Code debug HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code
Version 1.10.2
Windows 10

I'm testing out VS Code and would like to debug some simple HTML and JavaScript.

The tutorial at http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/debugging states 'Debugging ... "just works"', and the video claims that **"You don't have to do any configuration to get simple files working."**

When I play a simple HTML file I get a "select environment" prompt.

When I play a simple JavaScript file I get the error "Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH."

Am I doing something wrong?
How *do* I debug with VS Code?

TIA

Comment: Sounds like you have to install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Comment: Why on Earth would I want to do that? Why on Earth should I have to? If this is indeed the case then I'll just write VS Code off as garbage and uninstall it.

Comment: Node.js is extremely useful. There is no reason to *not* have it installed.

Comment: Not really pertinent to the topic at hand, Node's utility is a topic for another day.  
You don't miss what you've never had. So, I guess I'll just soldier on without it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Sumner Evans is correct.

Despite smugly touting 'Debugging that "just works"' Node.js must be installed before even basic debugging is available.